# Finding % based on multiple cells and using MATCH formula

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

Trying to come up with a formula for a spreadsheet I am working on, but hit a road block.

I need to use an INDEX and MATCH formula to ensure that the cell is going to lookup a sheet full of data and find all matches based on an ID number. I then need to work out the % value of how often that column was populated with data for that ID number.

Essentially as an example:

The data table would look like:

```
ID | Notes Added  
1  | Yes 
7  | Yes 
12 | Yes 
6  | Yes 
10 |  
12 |
```

And the result would be:

```
ID | Populated %
12 | 50 %
```

As you can see, the values that it should return would be 50%, as there are 2 entries that are listed for the ID of 12 (this is where the MATCH and INDEX would come in), however in the Notes Added, only 1 of the entries has a value.

The data table that it draws from will either have a value, or have no value, calculating the % would be based on if there is/isn't a value.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [COUNTIFS Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842). It would look something like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(B4:B9,C16,C4:C9,"Yes") / COUNTIF(B4:B9,C16)

=COUNTIFS(<ID Values Range>,<Id Value>,<notes added range>,"Yes") / COUNTIF(<ID Values Range>,<Id Value>)
```

Then just set the cell formatting to %.